# pyTelebot. Проблема с отправкой сообщений

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot, случайные-числа

Передо мной стоит задача, сделать бота на библиотеке pyTelegramBot, который будет **дублировать сообщения пользователя**, которые он будет получать и ещё, чтобы когда он находит в сообщении от пользователя слово "рандом" в любом регистре (нужно приводить к нижнему), он выводил: **Случайное число: (тут число)**. Моя проблема заключается в том, что первую функцию он выполняет, а вот на рандом он никак не реагирует, просто дублирует сообщение. Лямбда-функцию использовать необязательно, это я просто пробовал разные варианты написания.

```
import telebot
import random
from bot_token import TOKEN

# Создание объекта класса TeleBot с токеном
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

# Декоратор, использующий хендлер, где тип контента - текст
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def echo(message):
    'Функция "эхо"'
    print(message)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

# Обработчик с использование лямбда-функции
@bot.message_handler(func= lambda x: x.text.lower() in ['рандом'])
def say_hello(message):
    'Рандомное число'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Случайное число: {random.uniform(0, 2147483647)}')


# Бесконечная проверка наличия сообщения
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

**P.s - Также, если получится, то можно осуществить вот такую штуку, она будет лучше:** *Бот отвечает на сообщение, в котором есть слово ‘рандом’ случайным числом, в любом другом случае дублирует сообщение пользователя. Используются два разных хэндлера*